# JTransforms FFT on Image

Tags: java, image-processing, fft

I have an image that I want to transform to the frequency domain using FFT, there seems to be a lack of libraries for this for Java but I have found two. One is JTransforms and the other was less well known and doesn't have a name.

With the less well known one the 2D could only have length vales of powers of two but had simple to use methods like `FastFourierTransform.fastFT(real, imaginary, true);` with the real being the 2D array of doubles full of every pixel values and the imaginary part being a 2D array the same size full of zeroes. The Boolean value would depend on a forward or reverse transform. This made sense to me and it worked except for the power of two requirement which ruined any transform I did (I initially added black space around the image to fit it to the closest power of two), what I am struggling with is working out how to use the equivalent methods for JTransforms and would appreciate any guidance in doing so. I will state what I am currently doing.

I believe the relevant class would be `DoubleFFT_2D`, its constructor takes a number of rows and columns which I would assume to be the width and height of my image. Because my image has no imaginary parts I think I can use `doubleFFT.realForwardFull(real);` which treats imaginary parts as zero and pass the real 2D array full of pixels. Unfortunately this doesn't work at all. The JavaDoc states `the input array must be of size rows*2*columns, with only the first rows*columns elements filled with real data` But I don't see how this related to my image and what I would have to do to meet this requirement.

Sorry about the lengthy and poor explanation, if any additional information is needed I would be happy to  provide it.

JTransforms Library and Docs can be found here: https://sites.google.com/site/piotrwendykier/software/jtransforms

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's too bad the documentation for JTransforms isn't available online other than a zipped [download](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtransforms/files/jtransforms/2.4/jtransforms-2.4-doc.zip/download). It's very complete and helpful, you should check it out!

To answer your question: [`DoubleFFT_2D.realForwardFull(double[][] a)`](http://wendykierp.github.io/JTransforms/apidocs/org/jtransforms/fft/DoubleFFT_2D.html#realForwardFull-double:A:A-) takes an array of real numbers (your pixels). However, the result of the FFT will have two output values for each input value - a the real and the imaginary part of each frequency bin. This is why your input array needs to be twice as big as the actual image array, with half of it empty / filled with zeroes.

Note that all the FFT functions use `a` not only for input, but also for output - this means any image data in there will be lost, so it might be desirable to copy to a different / larger array anyway!

The easy and obvious fix for your scenario would be to use [`DoubleFFT_2D.realForward(double[][] a)`](http://wendykierp.github.io/JTransforms/apidocs/org/jtransforms/fft/DoubleFFT_2D.html#realForward-double:A:A-) instead. This one will only calculate the positive spectrum, because the negative side will be symmetrical to it. This is because your input values are real.

Also, check out the [`RealFFTUtils_2D`](http://wendykierp.github.io/JTransforms/apidocs/org/jtransforms/fft/RealFFTUtils_2D.html) class in JTransforms, which will make it a lot easier for you to retrieve your results from the array afterwards :)

Comment: Actually, it appears the (newer) docs are now online at github: http://wendykierp.github.io/JTransforms/apidocs/